# How to change the range of voltage?

Tags: voltage

I am doing a project to use dsPIC as controller to output PWM signal to control motors. I can use driver IC (I used L293D actually) to simply let motors to rotate, but I cannot control the voltage range to control the motor to rotate with all range of speed.

The output of dsPIC PWM pins is in the range of 0V~5V, but for motors, the input range is different.

Assume the range is -10V~10V, I want to change the 0~5V output to -10V~10V (0V->-10V, 5V->10V). Is there a good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assumptions:

- The circuit has +10V and -10V supply rails available
- Isolation of the dsPIC from the motor power / ground rails is desirable, to prevent back-EMF from frying the dsPIC

The following arrangement would provide arbitrary voltage switching, isolated from the controller side of the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmmr0K.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This will provide an inverted PWM signal to power the motor.

- The PWM signal switches the optocoupler's internal LED on and off.
- This turns the output phototransistor of the optocoupler on and off correspondingly.
- When the PWM signal is high, the opto's transistor conducts, pulling the MOSFET gate low, and thus it behaves as an open switch.
- When the PWM signal is low, the opto's transistor does not conduct, so the MOSFET's gate is pulled high, it behaves as a closed switch, allowing current through.
- The diode across the motor prevents back-EMF from frying the MOSFET.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation: )
I am a beginner, I want to ask that is this the standard way to drive motor?(is the current of the circuit in your answer big enough? sorry I don't know how to simulate in circuitLab)

Comment: @Ricky Since the question does not state any current requirement, there is no way to say whether 
"current is big enough". However, search Digikey for N-MOSFETs that meet your requirement parameters, and see their datasheets, to find something that suits your design specifications.

Comment: Sorry for that question, I understand now.And thanks a lot~

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned any way of driving **current** into the motors. Boosting the voltage out of the micro pin is not the problem, the problem is the micro pin can only source a tiny bit of current (5mA maybe) whereas even a small motor may draw an amp or more.

By the sound of it you are using a DC motor (not a stepper motor), so the usual way of driving this is with an H-Bridge.

Google will throw up hundreds of motor driver chips, circuits, etc.

Comment: Sorry for not stating clear in my question, I used driver IC to drive DC motor(so the current is large enough). But still I cannot change the driver IC output to the range I want.

Comment: So, does the chip accept a variable-voltage input or is it a logic-level on/off fwd/reverse affair?

Comment: The L293D driver IC chip is a logic-level on/off fwd/reverse affair~ (I used proteus to simulate, and I found only this driver IC)

Comment: @Ricky small dc motors can be speed controlled by connecting a pwm output to the enable input of the L293D.

Comment: @PeteKirkham Thanks~so can I get the relationship between duty cycle of PWM signal and the speed?(maybe the relationship is linear?)

Comment: @Ricky the relationship isn't linear, and will depend on the load, the motor's KV (rpm per volt) and inertial effects ( different motors behave differently to being pwm'd rather than having a constant voltage applied ). If you need accurate speed control, you'd have to add feedback, or you can calibrate the system for rough control ( which is good enough for model railways - for each engine, I record the pwm duty for just overcoming friction enough to crawl, slow, medium and fast, then smoothly ramp between it). It depends on your application what you need.

Comment: @PeteKirkham Thanks for the explanation, I think I need to play around with motors in Proteus more( or even write a simple controller by getting the current feedback).

Comment: You might need to play round with motors in real life a bit more too, a simulated motor is going to differ greatly from the behaviour of a real one in a given application.